# How to use cut and paste commands as a single line command?

Tags: linux, unix

In Unix, I am trying to write a sequence of cut and paste commands (saving result of each command in a file) that inverts every name in the file(below) shortlist and places a coma after the last name(for example, bill johnson becomes johnson, bill).

here is my file shortlist:

```
2233:charles harris  :g.m.     :sales     :12/12/52: 90000
9876:bill johnson    :director :production:03/12/50:130000
5678:robert dylan    :d.g.m.   :marketing :04/19/43: 85000
2365:john woodcock   :director :personnel :05/11/47:120000
5423:barry wood      :chairman :admin     :08/30/56:160000
```

I am able to cut from shortlist but not sure how to paste it on to my filenew file in same command line. Here is my code for cut:

```
cut -d: -f2 shortlist
```

result:

```
charles harris
bill johnson
robert dylan
john woodcock
barry wood
```

Now I want this to be pasted in my filenew file and when I cat filenew, result should look like below,

```
harris, charles
johnson, bill
dylan, robert
woodcock, john
wood, barry
```

Please guide me through this. Thank you.

Comment: Does the shortlist file ever contain entries like `jane x. smith` or `dr elizabeth jones` or any other format of name beyond two words separated by a space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a single awk:

```
awk -F: '{split($2,a, / /); if(a[2]) l=a[2] ", "; print l a[1]}' shortlist
```

I am assuming that if you don't have a second name, you don't want to print the comma (and you don't have more than 2 words in the name).

Comment: I find your requirement to use only cut/paste unusual. But with GNU cut which provides `--output-delimiter`, you can do with 2 cuts. But this will have the trailing comma/space. `cut -d: -f2 --output-delimiter="," shortlist | cut -d' ' --output-delimiter=", " -f2,1`

Comment: Note that GNU `cut` (in line with POSIX [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) requirements) neither repeats nor reorders fields. You can request a given field multiple times and it will appear once; you can seek to reorder fields with `-f 2,1` but the fields will be output in the order `field1 field2`.  This caught me by surprise when I was checking an answer of my own. (I have an old implementation of `cut` that doesn't behave like that; given `-f 2,1,2,1`, it would output `harris charles harris charles`).

Answer (score 1):

Once you've used `cut` to split up the string, it may be easier to use `awk` than `paste` to produce the result you want:

```
$ cut -d":" -f2 shortlist | awk '{printf "%s, %s\n", $2, $1}'
```

Comment: My commands needs to be using only cut and paste. I can't use awk with cut. I was able to get the result using awk but I need to get it using paste